# echo from the submission form value with different IDs

Tags: php, echo

I have a submission form with three of them

two of them are okay which I use one ID for all the value that going to be submit

but one of them which I'm struggling now is the one with all different values of course and the selection form also with different ID which made me confuse how can I echo it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
        <legend>เลือกช่อง</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="ch41" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">number 1</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="ch80" />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">number 2</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="ch44"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3>"number 3</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="ch42"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">number 4</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-5" value="ch83"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-5">number 5</label>
    </fieldset>
</div> 
</form>
```

and here is what I'm trying to echo

```
<video width="5%" height="5%" src="http://mydomain:<?php echo $_POST["radio-choice-1"]; ?>-<?php echo $_POST["date"]; ?>-<?php echo $_POST["time"]; ?>" alt="" controls="" tabindex="0">
```

so the problem is on the `"radio-choice-#"`

since it has 5 numbers on the ID

---

here is the example

```
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="ch80" />
        <label for="radio-choice-2">number 2</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="ch44"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-3>"number 3</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="ch42"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-4">number 4</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-5" value="ch83"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-5">number 5</label>
```

so if they choose menu number 5

I want to echo here

```
<video width="5%" height="5%" src="http://mydomain:<?php echo $_POST["the value of number 5"]; ?">
```

Comment: Two things I noticed: 1) You're missing the closing '>' on number 3 and 2) You're defining the name and id attributes twice on all of your radio buttons. Also, a specific ID can only be used *once*, syntactically. You can't define a division and five radio buttons to have the same ID.

Comment: fyi, you are missing a bracket on the `label` for radio-choice-3. `<label for="radio-choice-3"number 3</label>` should be `<label for="radio-choice-3">number 3</label>`

Comment: @animuson sorry I forgot to post the original one; I posted the one that I was playing around with it [the one I said struggling on]

Comment: @Kelly Cook thanks thats been fixed this wasn't the original one that is why; the original nothing missing [brackets]

Comment: @animuson so will it be possible somehow to get the php echo if they choose option one it will insert like radio-choice-1 and if they choose the number 5 it will insert "radio-choice-5 instead?

Comment: You also have a closing `</select>` with no open, and the closing `</div` is missing the `>`.

Comment: @Doug Kress really sorry I was in rush and forgot to check before I post here

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about what you're trying to achieve. Could you give an example of what the 'src' attribute should look like filled in? What do you want all the variables to equate too for each option?

Comment: @animuson to make it simple how can I echo the value in the embed

Example added on the top post

Comment: Well, if you're trying to echo in the 'ch##' value, then the way you have it set up should work. When multiple radio buttons have the same name, the radio button which is checked is the the value that is returned with the POST call. So if 'radio-choice-5' (by ID) is checked, then `$_POST['radio-choice-1']` would return `ch83`.

Comment: @animuson thanks thats work!!

one last thing sorry to disturbing you

will it will somehow possible to display the option they choose after the form been submitted? like if they choose number 5

on the top or bottom will say you are on page number 5 or something like that

I believe that can be done with php or ajax but not sure

Comment: @animuson it will be so much appreciated if you can write up as an answer so that I can accept the answer that you answered here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for actually getting the value from the radio button was already correct. Here is something you could use to keep data more organized and be able to get the 'page' number you're on.

```
<?php
$items = array('ch41', 'ch80', 'ch44', 'ch42', 'ch83');
$page = array_search((empty($_POST['choice']) ? 'ch41' : $_POST['choice']), $items) + 1; // Change 'ch41' to whatever the default page is
// To name the labels, you can add keys for your values like so:
$items = array('home' => 'ch41', 'page' => 'ch80', 'channel' => 'ch44', 'news' => 'ch42', 'contact' => 'ch83');
$page = (empty($_POST['choice']) ? 'home' : array_search($_POST['choice'], $items)); // Replace 'home' with whatever the default page is
// Then replace the <?= $key + 1 ?> below with just <?= $key ?>
?>
You are currently on page <?= $page ?>.
<form action="" method="post">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <legend>เลือกช่อง</legend>
<?php foreach ($items as $key => $value): ?>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio-choice-<?= $key ?>" value="<?= $value ?>"<?= $key === $_POST['choice'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ?> />
        <label for="radio-choice-<?= $key ?>">number <?= $key + 1 ?></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</fieldset>
</div> 
</form>
```

A rough example. You can add additional channels to the `$items` array. It will default to page 1 and automatically check the radio button for the page you're currently viewing. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: The code work perfectly and thank you so much


quick question on the lebel <label for="radio-choice-<?= $key ?>">number <?= $key + 1 ?></label> how can I name the label instead of using number 1,2,3,4,5  to be something else like

home, page, channel, news, contact

Comment: I have modified the code above. Also remove the `number` text in front of the PHP output if you use that method.

Comment: sorry maybe I wasn't make it clear on my comment above

the code you gave me was perfect but except one thing that I'm trying to make the label display like


        <label for="radio-choice-3>"Home</label>

        <label for="radio-choice-3>"Page</label>

        <label for="radio-choice-3>"Contact</label>

Comment: sorry please ignore my noobies I just notice you have edit that I have to change the $key :)

Comment: I guess you already gone by now but there is an error in the code where when you submit the form the > You are currently on page <?= $page ?>. only display the same page it won't change when the page been submit, I tried look at them but couldn't find what is wrong with the code

Comment: Sorry about that, I've fixed it. I was just thinking about default page forget to check the actual page.